# I want to create a web application using spring3.0 and java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am new into software development.so may be you think my question is silly and i am sorry for that.
              I want to create a web application using J2EE. i am planning to use spring 3.0 framework along with hibernate. for view i want to use freemarker and batabase i prefer postgresql. IDE i am using eclipse HELIOS. i can do the coding but the main problem is initial configuration before starting the development. so can any body help me how to configure what are the code needed in what xml files.I dont know how to configure all these thing i want to use annotation and MVC pattern so please any body know how i start please ans me.....

Comment: you will have lot articles in google , that might be the best place , SO is manly for logic related questions if you get stuck or so

Comment: @kobe: I disagree, there's often so many articles it's hard to know where to start. I think SO is perfect for getting opinions on a good article to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you are really confuse about how to start, as i see you don't have that much expierice on web application (correct me if i'm wrong), first thing you need to do if to understand wether Java and specially a Spring architecture is your best options (or your only for that matter), there are a  lot of easier way to build web application and trust me i love java but sometimes is just so big and with so many options about building anything (specially webapplication) that is really overwhelming.

Anyway if you are decide it to take a Spring 3.x for building your web application you migh wanna start with the basic a typical architecture like this one:

[image]

- WebLayer will be Spring MVC
- Service Layer a bunch of Spring
  object instantiated by spring
  (usually @Transactional)
- Data Layer will  be hibernate POJO
  and Data Access Objects(@Repository)

**Where to Start?**

Well there are a lot of [documentation](http://www.springsource.org/documentation) i must say that spring guy have done an amazing job on this matter.

About using freemarker is easy to plug it with spring here is an [article](http://mf9it.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/integration-of-freemarker-and-spring/) to do it but also is on the official documentation [Integrating View Technologies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.4/reference/view.html).

**Tools you can use**

Since you are basing everything on Spring,  [Spring Suite Tool](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) can do the trick ;)

Comment: yes buddy u r correct thing is that i joined one company which is product based company i get chance to enhance that product by adding new module but initial configuration already made by seniors so i dont know how to configure but i know the how to code if application is already configured thats my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

It'll get you up and running with a Spring MVC project which contains all the components in your question

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at **AppFuse** by Matt Raible: http://appfuse.org

Starting off with the "light" version might be a good idea, but it sure has helped me to get started and learn new frameworks in the past. So generating a (readily deployable) project with Spring, Hibernate and a Web-Framework and Database of your choice will be quite easy.

If you want to stick more closely to Spring, try http://www.springsource.org/roo